# Join with indices (not database index) of right table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a one to many relationship and want to join the right table while including an index number for each of the rows on the many table.

For instance:

user table

```
id | name
 1 | me
 2 | you

attempted table
user_id | date 
      1 | 2014-03-01
      1 | 2014-03-03
      1 | 2014-03-02
      2 | 2014-02-01

join result
user_name | date       | attempt_number
       me | 2014-03-01 | 0     
       me | 2014-03-02 | 1
       me | 2014-03-03 | 2
      you | 2014-02-01 | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for the enumeration.

```
select u.name, a.date,
       (row_number() over (partition by u.name order by a.date) - 1) as attempt_number
from user u left outer join
     attempted a
     on a.user_id = u.id;
```

EDIT:

I struggle with the type of `join` here.  The sample data only has one user name in it, "me", yet the sample output has two, "me" and "you".  The `attempted` table references two user ids.

I am assuming that the relevant tables are just truncated for the question, and that the user ids in `attempted` have a proper foreign key relationship to the `user` table.  Hence, this query uses a `left outer join`, which keeps all the rows from the `user` table.  It could also just use an `inner join`.

Comment: I think, it should be a `right join` since OP wants all data of `attempted` table.

Comment: @Rahul . . . I know.  See my explanation in the answer.

Comment: I forgot the "you" row in the user table and have updated.  I use an inner join for this and it works great.